# How to annotate high order function with arguments forwarding

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, flowtype

I'm trying to annotate this composition:

```
const get1 = (n: number, s: string) => `${n}_${s}`;
const get2 = (s: string, n: number) => `${n}_${s}`;

const foo = (get) => (...args) => {
    get(...args);
}

const foo1= foo(get1);
const foo2= foo(get2);


foo1(2, 'qwe');
foo2('qwe', 1)
```

Currently I'm using the Flow as type checker but I'm also interested in TypeScript answers as it can be a good point for me to migrate.

Comment: this is the `apply` function and difficult to annotate in a meaningful way. Because `get` could be any function with any input and any output, and `...args` can be of any type, `apply` becomes "any function, and any args, yields any output"...

Comment: compare that to `const foo = <A, B> (get: A => B, x: A): B => get (x)` which has a meaningful annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the flow version:

```
const get1 = (n: number, s: string) => `${n}_${s}`;
const get2 = (s: string, n: number) => `${n}_${s}`;

const foo = <A: mixed[], R>(get: (...A) => R): ((...A) => R) => 
  (...args: A): R =>
    get(...args);

const foo1= foo(get1);
const foo2= foo(get2);


foo1(2, 'qwe');
foo2('qwe', 1);
// $ExpectError
foo1('qwe', 2);
// $ExpectError
foo2(2, 'qwe');

foo2('qwe', 1, 3); // this should probably error but doesn't
```

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygRhgXhgCjALhmAVwFsAjBAJwBoYI9pyBLMOASnQD4YADAEgG8wAXwD6-CIK4BuAFChIsRFABM6LLRpRGzarnzEy5Nmk68BIsRJmzw0GADMQIVQB4AgniIMAHggAmAbQBdagAldkxFPEwAOljXI04QliiYuISYJI4YaRgsWOiAQ3I4dXi8EI4c3PgkVMLiiBYrOVsHEGQMNoikZCbreXtHJU7HbuU+6Wk25EwlagByAEcAdwR5vralTCXV+epemQB6Q5geAFEvAAcEYCgz8nIQcinHGZ216iU+49OL69v7o9nptZgsVmsJiD3nsYMhqABmJowH5QAAWDAgNFRIAIABtfDBLo8SAUSLiAJ4wChAmAkAiwXwgBAQMDzKBAA))

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach you could use with this example:

```js
const get1 = (n: number, s: string) => `${n}_${s}`;
const get2 = (s: string, n: number) => `${n}_${s}`;

const foo = <T extends any[], R>(get: (...args: T) => R) => (...args: T): R => {
  return get(...args);
};

const foo1 = foo(get1);
const foo2 = foo(get2);

foo1(2, "qwe");
foo2("qwe", 1);
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygRhgXhgCjALhmAVwFsAjBAJwBoYI9pyBLMOASnQD4YADAEgG8wAXwD6-CIK4BuALAAoUJFiIoAJnRZaNKI2bVc+YmXJs0nXgJFiJM2XIXQYAMxAh1AHgAqMBAA8oCMAATCBgAQzAATwBtAF1qACV2TGU8TAA6DNDyOE0PE054-KwMtKycvDy8eI4YPjkYGHIkAnIweCR0zOyIFhtBGztwB2cQVAwR5KRkXsHFJxc1cZdJ1RnbWRHkTBVqACIARwB3BF21kZVMA+Pd6mmbIA)

If you're new to TypeScript, this example relies on [Generics](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/generics.html) and [Rest Parameters](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/rest-parameters.html). Specifically, Rest Generics in this example were added in [3.0](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#generic-rest-parameters).

Comment: From the [Flow docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/any/): _If you want a way to opt-out of using the type checker, `any` is the way to do it. **Using `any` is completely unsafe, and should be avoided whenever possible.**_

Answer (score -1):

Came up with the following solution:

```
// @flow

const get1 = (n: number, s: string) => `${n}_${s}`;
const get2 = (s: string) => `_${s}`;

type Apply<T, R> = (...args: T) => R

const foo = <TArgs: *>(get: Apply<TArgs, string>): Apply<TArgs, Promise<*>> =>
    (...args) => {
        const str = get(...args);

        return Promise.resolve(str);
    }


const foo1= foo(get1);
const foo2= foo(get2);


foo1(1, 'qwe');
foo2('qwe');

// $ExpectError      
foo2('qwe', 'qwer') //wrong arity
// $ExpectError 
foo2('qwe', 2, 3, 5, 6, 4) //wrong arity
// $ExpectError 
foo1(1, 'qwe', 3, 5, 6) //wrong arity
```

This example has one more addition that I'm not returning result of get but just use it inside the function.

Looks like it works almost correctly. The one thing missing is the arity of foo1 and foo2. But at least type checks work correctly

Thanks all to your answers

Comment: https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDGsB2BnALqA5gKbYCMoAvKABToBco6ArgLYBGBATgDSiZ07sBLdHgCU5AHygABgBIA3ugC+AfXmZFUgNyoMOfEQBM5Krx7ZBwsWUlTVc9VuTYAngAcCoAIKvX0ZwB4AFW4AJUkKSgA6aIBDdjxTQKtJEMRQdNAdLFxIWFhjIM940wAqcUpCbDpvXwDAooTufiE8cRFqnz9C4u4ABXZYJgFMAn8y8PE0jKjY4uTQOSn0gEg0bLN2Y0qZyLiEkW0Mo4yl4-YiBnZ0UH7B4YJI88xYaAA3Akp+A9PFU7+1vS5WDEChAipEYjfAE5PIGUF5cHYAzfZBA4iUYjcADkAEd4AQsd8gQZKLj8YTDscjogQKAZABRAAe7hQ2Hp7AGm2OiGJpLxBOx-PYhNAIHgA2EoDiAhcNLADOZBFZ7M5mV5ZIFoAM3AAzNwAKzcABs3AALGIxRK8FLBLLaQqWWyObBNjy8ujMaANVjdQbjRbgOKMNbpbKqdSgA

Comment: This uses the existential operator `*` which is deprecated.

Comment: ha, haven't noticed when it became deprecated. The last thing I remember from Flow docs was that they recommended to use * instead of any as it could work a little bit better